# Executing a recursive function using actionButton causes "error: c stack usage" (shiny)

Tags: r, recursion, shiny

I am creating a shiny app where the user can enter a matrix, then click a play button and it progressively applies Gauss-Jordan elimination. The core of the app is the `apply_gauss_jordan_3d` function, which gets as an input a 3x3 A matrix and I3, applies Gauss-Jordan one step and returns a list with the modified A' and I' matrices. I want the "renderTable" function to execute in two scenarios: (1) when a user changes the input matrix and (2) when the user presses the action button. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
# Create user interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  titlePanel(
    headerPanel("Linear Transformations")
  ),
  withMathJax(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons(
        "dimension", 
        label = "Choose number of dimensions", 
        choices = c("2D", "3D"), 
        selected = "2D"
      ),
      matrixInput(
        "transform_mat",
        label = "Input the transformation matrix",
        value = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE),
        rows = list(names = FALSE),
        cols = list(names = FALSE),
        class = "numeric",
        copy = TRUE,
        paste = TRUE
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Plot",  plotlyOutput("plot")),
        tabPanel("Null Space", verbatimTextOutput("null_space"), plotlyOutput("null_space_plot")),
        tabPanel("Determinant", uiOutput("determinant")),
        tabPanel(
          "Gauss-Jordan", 
          tableOutput("gauss_matrix"), 
          tableOutput("gauss_identity"), 
          actionButton("rewind", "", icon = icon("fast-backward")),
          actionButton("play", "", icon = icon("play")),
          actionButton("advance", "", icon = icon("fast-forward"))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


# Define server function
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$dimension, {
    mat_options <- list(
      "2D" = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE),
      "3D" = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE)
    )
    updateMatrixInput(
      session, 
      "transform_mat", 
      value = mat_options[[input$dimension]]
    )
  })
  mat_list <- reactive(
    list(
      input$transform_mat,
      diag(as.numeric(str_remove(input$dimension, "D")))
    )
  )
  mat_list <- eventReactive(input$play, {
    apply_gauss_jordan_3d(mat_list()[[1]], mat_list()[[1]])
  })  
  output$gauss_matrix <- renderTable({
    mat_list()[[1]]
  }, colnames = FALSE)
  output$gauss_identity <- renderTable({
    mat_list()[[2]]
  }, colnames = FALSE)
}

# Run shiny application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, when I execute it I get the following error:

```
Error in : C stack usage  7969216 is too close to the limit
```

The computation itself is not expensive at all, but I guess it enters in an infinite recurssion somehow. Do you know how I could tweak it to avoid this issue?

Cheers

Comment: I can't find the ```apply_gauss_jordan_3d``` function, did you define it yourself? If so, can you include the code for this?

Comment: You can find the function definitions [here](https://github.com/massonix/math_teaching/blob/master/utils.R)

Comment: @bretauv Did you find anything useful? Thanks a lot :)!

Comment: unfortunately, I've never suffered from this problem so I can't help you but there are plenty of SO links with this error message, maybe you'll find a solution with these. I edited your post though